# Dynamic (on the fly) generation of django models from mongodb

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, django-nonrel

I want to be able to generate html representation of some mongoDB collection, say simple table.

is it posible to do this without fixed models, because there is no known collection structure in advance.

What would be best approach here?

I'm using [django-mongodb](http://django-mongodb.org) along with [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel)

Comment: Do you really need the models in your case? Maybe you should just do normal raw queries to mongodb without caring about django or models.

Comment: Than't good point. I wanted to utilaze existing django goodies of MVC... any other proposition here?

Answer (score 0):

I have very little knowledge about mongodb, as I understand you get dict as query result.

Main question is what model should encapsulate ?

Old fashion way:

```
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self, voice=None, **kwargs):
        self.voice = voice

    def bark(self):
        print self.voice

data = assuming_that_django_mongodb_data_is_dict_and_voice_is_included
dog = Dog(**data)
```

Dead brain cells method:

```
class AnyModel(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for name, value in kwargs.iter():
            setattr(self, name, value)
```

I think, it would be nice to have queryset objects, but this is not that easy, at least for me.